# mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away - php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, connection, database-connection

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in functions.php on line 2108'

ErrorException: mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in functions.php on line 2108

=================

I have a php script running for 40-50mins and connects to DBs on 2 different machines in the cloud, inserting and updating multi_queries, but from time to time fails at a simple select almost at the end of the script. Machines are Windows Server 2008R2.

I have played with the parameters for both Apache and MySQL as suggested on different posts.
I've also made a reset connection function to reset the DB connection from to time, but i still end up with the error above.
My script fits in many scenarios in [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html), but at least resetting the connection should work. Besides resetting the connection in the function i also close it only once at the end of the php script.

What is the proper way to at least reset the connection?

MySQL my.ini:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 128M
connect-timeout=10800
wait_timeout = 28800
```

Apache:

```
KeepAlive On
```

Php reset function

```
function reset_connection()
{
$counter = 100;
$sleep_time = 100;
global $sql,$SERVER,$user,$pass,$db_name,$port;

    $sql->close();
    $sql= new mysqli($SERVER, $user, $pass, $db_name, $port);

    while (mysqli_connect_errno() && $counter>0)
    {
        sleep($sleep_time);
        $counter--;

        printf("Connect failed retrying:".mysqli_connect_error());
        $sql= new mysqli($SERVER, $user, $pass, $db_name, $port);
    }

    if(mysqli_connect_errno() || $counter<=0)
    {
        printf("Connect failed".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: isnt 40-50 min to long for a php script execution, what about running it as a cron job?

Comment: i know maybe the queries and multi queries are not optimized yet, but the accumulated time is due to waiting for responses from other API's.